# Installing Hyperledger Fabric as normal user in Linux throws the error

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I refered link

https://github.com/jollen/Hyperledger-Fabric-Install

as I started installing hyperledger fabric on commmand "make configtxgen" it throws me the error

> Makefile:66: *** "No go in PATH: Check dependencies".  Stop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not have the Go compiler installed and/or located in your PATH.  There is a section on the link you referenced about installing Go, adding it to your profile and then sourcing the profile.  If you don't do this in the current terminal session, Go will not be found in your PATH.  (logging in and out will also make it available).

FYI - The link you referenced is pretty old ... if you are in fact just trying to install and get up and running with Fabric I'd suggest you actually use the Fabric getting started documentation ( http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.2/getting_started.html ).